# Python redmine collect actual start date and actual completion date

Tags: python, python-redmine

I am trying to collect the **actual issue start** date and **actual completion date** from my company Redmine using Python-Redmine. But I CAN NOT find out the attribute of **actual completion date**.
[image: sample screen shot]

I tried some common phrases like actual_completion_date/actual_due_date.. and also checked on https://python-redmine.com/resources/issue.html for the right attribute name. However, still stuck here.

This is my code:

```
from redminelib import Redmine 
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

redmine = Redmine('https://abc.xyz.com', key=keyRedmine,requests={'verify': False})
issue = redmine.issue.get(326264)
print('start date: ', issue.start_date)
print('actual start date: ', issue.actual_start_date)
print('due date: ', issue.due_date)
print ('actual end date: N/A') # I want to find this value
```

And here is my output:

```
start date:  2021-03-03
actual start date:  2021-07-03
due date:  2021-08-25
actual end date: N/A
```

When I try with my guessed phrase:

```
print ('actual end date: ',issue.actual_due_date)
```

The output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/test.py", line 22, in <module>
    print ('actual end date: ',issue.actual_due_date)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\redminelib\resources\standard.py", line 152, in __getattr__
    return super(Issue, self).__getattr__(attr)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\redminelib\resources\base.py", line 197, in __getattr__
    raise exceptions.ResourceAttrError
redminelib.exceptions.ResourceAttrError: Resource doesn't have the requested attribute
```

Could you help me with how to get the **actual end date** for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the way for this attribute name. It is `actual_due_date`.

I got it from:

- Go to redmine page,
- Press <kbd>F12</kbd>,
- Select "issue" on the left side tree and
- Select "Console" on the top bar.

Then find your attributes here. In my case like

[image]